# React bootstrap icons doesnt work when I import bootstrap

Tags: javascript, react-router, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-icons, react-bootstrap-icons

I don't see the bootstrap icons in a NavLink component when I import bootstrap.css.

I have a react project, I installed bootstrap using `npm i bootstrap` and I also installed react-bootstrap-icons using `npm i react-bootstrap-icons`.
I imported bootstrap in index.js file (`import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"`;)
and one of my child components is using an icon:

```
import { DoorClosed } from "react-bootstrap-icons";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Header() {
  <NavLink to="/Login">
    <span className="logoutIcon-container tooltip" id="logoutBtn">
      <DoorClosed size={96} color="white" />
      <span className="tooltipText">Logout</span>
    </span>
  </NavLink>
}
```

But I do not see the icon. I have two solutions for the icon to show up, but none of them fit my project:

1. I can import the bootstrap grid system `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css"` instead of `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"` in index.js. (But, I no longer will be able to use bootstrap classes in my project.)
2. I can move the icon outside of the `<NavLink/>` component. (But I need it to be inside the component)

Any better solution?

Comment: Yes the problem was tooltip, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The `Header` component needs to return something to render, e.g. it should return the `NavLink` and rest of the JSX.
- I don't exactly know why the `"tooltip"` class is added to your link, but the issue here is that it sets an `opacity: 0;` CSS rule which makes the rendered UI not visible. Remove the `"tooltip"` class.

Code:

```
function Header() {
  return (                               // <-- Return JSX
    <NavLink to="/Login">
      <span
        className="logoutIcon-container" // <-- Remove "tooltip" class
        id="logoutBtn"
      >
        <DoorClosed size={96} color="white" />
        <span className="tooltipText">Logout</span>
      </span>
    </NavLink>
  );
}
```

[image]